# Can't figure out how to debug a bad access error ~> C

Tags: c, debugging

So, I have this code:

```
void stringCounter( char cp[], int counter[] ) {

char c;
for ( int i = 0; strlen(cp); i++ ) {
   c = cp[i];
   // Checking to see if the variable c is alphanumeric...
   if ( isalnum(c) ) {
      if ( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' ) {
         counter[c - 'A']++;
      } else {
         counter[26]++;
      }
   }
   }
return;
}
```

And I have a bad access error on line 5 (of my listed code). I really don't know how to fix this error! I have tried making things pointers, tried not making things pointers, but really can't get it. Usually, I can debug my programs fairly well, but I am really having trouble with this one.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On which compiler and system are you working? Did you enable all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux)? Did you learn how to use your debugger (e.g. `gdb`)?

Comment: Using Mac XCode, and yeah I know how to debug that. I just wasn't looking at the right line of code to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition should be `i < strlen(cp)`, not just `strlen(cp)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply incrementing `i` without any boundary checking

```
   for ( int i = 0; i< strlen(cp); i++ ) {
                     ^^ fix this
```